# Amazon [Ec2 Linux Instance] SSH not working after increasing Open Files / File Descriptors (FD)

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, ulimit

I am not able to `ssh` my ec2 instance [linux based] after I have executed following command. [Before that I am able to ssh to server]

```
# vim /etc/sysctl.conf
```

I have update file-max number to 4000000

```
fs.file-max = 4000000
```

Also I have edited:

`# vi /etc/security/limits.conf`

Add following lines at end

`* soft nofile 4000000`
`* hard nofile 4000000`

Then I exit my ec2 insatnce & try to ssh again but of no luck.

I have tried ssh with -v option & what I get is only

```
debug1: Exit status 254
```

Note: This is the only change I have made.

Comment: did you try to put it back to previous valut and verify that it is really the trigger?

Comment: since I am not able to ssh server it means that change is already reflected

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify, after editing the file for the descriptor limit change, what else have you done?  On its own, modifying the file changes nothing, and should have no effect.  The change may even be incorrect, for example if a different character was entered somewhere else in the file.

In particular, can you clarify if

- you logged out afterwards?
- initiated a reboot?

It's also not clear whether

- you have tried to reboot from the management console?
- you have tried to see if there's any network issue coincident with your issue?
- you have tried logging in from somewhere else (different IP)?

If everything checks out, and you are unable to get back to the system in any other way, you may need to follow the AWS documentation about [How To Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598).

What it seems to be is replacing the virtual hard drive with a new one with a fresh system, and investigating the "old" hard drive from within the new system, salvaging anything important in the process, *including reviewing the old logs* to see what the actual effect on the system was.

*Update* - there was a comment earlier to suggest similar things happened when the limit was increased.  I just tested (and found hints elsewhere) that the maximum `nofile` setting is `1048576` (i.e. 1024*1024, 2^20).  If I use anything higher on my Linux box, it will just revert to 1024 as the highest, but won't cause a problem.  Perhaps the distribution you are using for AWS is not as forgiving, and either rolls over the limit, and/or considers the failure to set an invalid limit fatal, and won't let you proceed with the login.

Note - the changes you make there are not instantaneous.  They take affect when you next login, and/or for any processes you restart from the newly logged in session - or for all processes after the reboot, but this is already too late for you case.

As I can't reproduce your problem, I'm not sure what way you can still access your box.  Perhaps sftp as root could have worked if there was not a reboot, with the reboot, this possibility may have gone.

For the next time, you may want to consider keeping an root ssh session running screen alive, in case you can't log in as root or use `su` again.  Perhaps even connected via mosh. This can be important when you change anything on the system that affects future logins.

You could also consider a cronjob scheduled 30 minutes later to restore the previous file, in case you can't get back in - but these must be prepared before the change itself, and may be prevented from running.

Unfortunately, if none of the remote access methods are working for you (including sftp as root, which is not a very good idea to do), then you may need to refer to the AWS documentation linked above to get recover the data on the host via a different instance.

Comment: After changing fs.file-max to 4000000

I have did 1 more change
# vi /etc/security/limits.conf

Add following lines at end
* soft nofile 4000000
* hard nofile 4000000

Comment: I simply disconnect ssh & try to login again. I have restarted instance either from amazon console or from shell

Comment: Just wanted to pitch in; I'm currently also experiencing the same issue : changed limits.conf in the same way (but set nofile to 65536), I'm not able to ssh in to the EC2 machine anymore. SSH also exits with 254.

Comment: Ok, I found out what I did to make ssh close the session every time. I also added "session required pam_limits.so" to /etc/pam.d/common-session (as was suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515463/how-to-increase-maximum-file-open-limit-ulimit-in-ubuntu) Unfortunately I don't  know why this caused the issue. If anyone can enlighten me ... ?

Comment: Ok, I found the issue myself : I made a type in "session required pam_limits.so", instead of pam_limits.so, I wrote pam_limitd.so with a d instead of s. This caused the ssh session to fail and close. So far for stability :S

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is some issue related to EC2 AMI.
To fix this issue.

1. Detach EBS from the EC2 instance
2. Add `fs.nr_open = 4000000` to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

   `fs.file-max = 4000000
   fs.nr_open = 4000000`
3. Attach EBS to EC2 instance
4. Reboot EC2 and login